# getBestProvider method is returning gps in a tablet without gps

Tags: android, gps, tablet, locationmanager

I have a little application where I use google maps api for Android. I have a method to get the best provider for the location manager:

```
public String getBestProvider(){
    String result = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;;

    try {

        String value = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;

        List<String> proveedores = locationManager.getAllProviders();           


        //Try to set the position with the gps
        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            value = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
        }
        else{
             Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
             value = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);                
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, value, 1000);

        result = value;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}
```

I have done that to force to my cell phone to get "GPS_PROVIDER" as best provider when it is enabled (my cell phone is a Samsung Galaxy S2, with Android 4.1.2). This is because using the order "locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);" didn't return the gps as best provider when it was active.

Well, by this way is working fine in my cell phone. But I have a tablet (Xtreme X81, Android 4.2.2 and without gps) where I have installed my application. I have tested it on the tablet and it doesn't work. I can't debug the application because I don't have the drivers for the tablet, but inserting messages with Toast I have seen that this method is returning me "GPS_PROVIDER" as best provider. Why is returning that? Is there any simplest way to improve the code to get the best provider for any device?

Thanks in advance,
Regards.

Comment: Most likely, it is because it is a low-quality tablet from a no-name manufacturer, and they screwed up either their marketing materials (and it really has GPS) or their firmware (and failed to configure their location providers correctly). In the latter case, they would not have passed the compatibility process. Assuming this is made by Mach Speed, [this help page](http://www.xtremetab.com/help/) suggests that it does not come with the Play Store, and so does not have to pass any compatibility tests.

Comment: So basically you are saying that my problem is basically for use a low quality tablet...Ok, I'll search for more info about the manufacturer and I'll try to test my application in other devices. Thanks for your response. When I have more info about this problem I will post it. Regards.